# How to connect IntelliJ to Google Cloud Development Git respository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've set up git repository on Google Cloud Development and pulled it using gcloud init. I'm now trying to connect IntelliJ to that repository on Google. IntelliJ asks for a VCS URL or should it be done with SSH keys?

Steps so far:

I've installed IntelliJ 14.1.5 which has built in VCS and Git. I start a project from Version Control and choose Git. It asks for a repository URL, and then Username and password. URL is https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-name/r/default username and password are my google info that I've registered with the project.

Comment: Can you list the steps you have already taken here?  Do you have the plugin running and does Git show up as an option in Project Settings?

Comment: Thanks Tim I've updated

Comment: I actually just configured Git in my IntelliJ 11 today, and it never asked me for a URL.  I believe that all IntelliJ needs is a `.git` repository file and it can figure out the rest.  What steps did you take to end up being prompted for a URL?

Comment: Opened IntelliJ 14, File>New> Project from Version Control>Git

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Development as your Git repository?

Comment: No I'm not.  Can you try just opening the project normally and then adding Git VCS afterwards?

Comment: I added the local respository URL and it worked. So when I push it will push to local. Then I have to push from local to Google Cloud. I'm going to try https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-intellij/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Sounds good and feel free to answer your own question.  I prefer using the Git bash for all operations except visualizing diffs and annotations which I do in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I added the local repository URL and it worked. So when I push it will push to local. Then I have to push from local to Google Cloud. There is also https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-intellij